# App keep crash when I click back from activity to main

Tags: android

I got this error message:

```
09-05 19:58:00.883: E/AndroidRuntime(21920): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause      activity {com.De7kat.Grid/com.De7kat.Grid.De7katGrid}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

when I go to activity 2 and try to back to activity 1 by clicking the back button on device.

`de7katgrid` activity code is:

```
package com.De7kat.Grid;


public class De7katGrid extends Activity {
private MediaPlayer mp;
public Integer[] mSongsIds = {
        R.raw.beet,R.raw.far,
        R.raw.beet,R.raw.far,
        R.raw.beet,R.raw.far,
        R.raw.beet,R.raw.far,
        R.raw.beet,R.raw.far,
        R.raw.beet,R.raw.far,
        R.raw.beet,R.raw.far,
        R.raw.beet,R.raw.far,
        R.raw.beet,R.raw.far,
        R.raw.beet,R.raw.far,
        R.raw.beet,R.raw.far,
        R.raw.beet,    };
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mSongsIds[position];
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
             stopPlaying();
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(De7katGrid.this,mSongsIds[position]);
             mp.start();

           }
    });
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
       mp.stop();



    }
}

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;


       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Stack trace, stack trace, stack trace. Making my best guess without it, I'd say it's because you're doing `mp.isPlaying()` in your `onPause()` without checking if `mp` is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return to your Activity `mp` is `null` after you call `create()` because you failed to release the previous one. Change your `onPause()` method like so:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopPlaying();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call your `stopPlaying()` method in `onPause()` ? It's better than duplicating the code (and you will get rid of the `NullPointerException`, which happens because you don't check if `mp` is null) :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopPlaying();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your mp is null when onPause is called.